# Concurrency, HashMaps and Lists

Tags: java

I'm using a `HashMap<String, Group>` to store a list of users and the permissions they can use, I know that there will be cases where this `HashMap` will need to be accessed from another thread, the same goes for the `List<String>` that a Group object returns when `getPermissions()` is called.

I've never really touched on concurrency properly, so I'm asking how I would make sure that method calls are Thread-safe. I've looked at the ConcurrentHashMap and the Java documentation/tutorials for using the synchronized keyword.

```
public List<String> getPermissions() {
    synchronized(this) {
        return permissions;
    }
}
```

Is this the appropriate way of accessing the permissions attached to my group or is there a better way? It may be worth noting that this list *will* have items added and removed from it.

Also if I used a `ConcurrentHashMap` am I correct in assuming that I do not need to use the synchronized keyword? Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**
I may have written this question in a way that confused people about the relevance of the List. At some point the HashMap is queried to retrieve a Group object, getPermissions is later called on the Group object. If a group does not exist then my code tries to create it using a default setup, put the object into the HashMap then return the *original* object, should I just return it from the HashMap?

Comment: Return a copy of the list, not the original - avoids concurrency issues and also prevents clients unexpectedly modifying your `permissions`.

Comment: @AlanStokes forgive me for such a nooby question; won't that also stop me updating the list directly? I need to be able to add and remove items in the list still.

Comment: Use [CopyOnWriteArrayList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). That's what it's made for.

Comment: Thanks @EddieB, using that for my List. Will use a ConcurrentHashMap for the HashMap.

Comment: Suit Yourself... [Joshua Bloch :: Effective Java](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA268&lpg=PA268&dq=joshua+bloch+copyonwritearraylist&source=bl&ots=yZDoPloZP3&sig=jR7dSiVmuUqMOjnEaPlh6S6MiCs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nfyfVJz7N4GfgwTDz4HQCg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=joshua%20bloch%20copyonwritearraylist&f=false)

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the resource. Would iterating through each Group object in a list and adding a `name` field and getter be more efficient than using a HashMap?

Comment: @Albion No, it wouldn't. Any changes you made wouldn't affect the list previously returned by `getPermissions` - which is normally a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `synchronized` or a `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: Thanks for answering the HashMap bit.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would suggest using [CopyOnWriteArrayList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) as it's a bit faster than ConcurrentHashMap.

> - A thread-safe variant of ArrayList in which all mutative operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array.
> - Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a CopyOnWriteArrayList **happen-before** actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the CopyOnWriteArrayList in another thread.

Comment: But an `ArrayList` isn't exactly a `HashMap` right?

Comment: I would definitely learn something new today if you tell me that you can use a string as an index for [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: That's a different topic. Using a string for an index is rarely a good idea. Primitives or their boxed wrappers are better... ideally int or long.

Comment: `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is a List<E> though.. not a List<T,E> as you claim?

Comment: @Albion Yes, `CopyOnWriteArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`

Comment: In what circumstances do you think it's faster? Copying the array on every mutation is not without cost.

Comment: @AlanStokes That's a good question. Generally speaking when you are implementing an Observer pattern or have a lot of `read` based accessors. Obviously it's not a good candidate for `write` heavy transactions.